# Как отправить данные формы обработчику?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма, отправка которой происходит через фрейм:

```
<form id="form" action="send.php" method="post" target="frame">
    <input type="text" name="size" placeholder="Размер *">
    <input type="text" name="form" placeholder="Форма *">
    <input type="submit" class="rounded_button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Заполнение полей проверяется плагином jQuery Validate, после проверки
выполняется функция отправки формы:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        size: {required: true},
        form: {required: true}
    },
    messages: {
        size: {required: false},
        form: {required: false}
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        sendForm();
    }
});

function sendForm() {
    $('#form').submit();
}
```

Форма отправляется, но сильно долго (15-20 секунд, иногда больше или браузер сам останавливает отправку) и страница зависает в любом браузере. Если убрать валидацию формы и прописать onSubmite="sendForm()" форме, то отправка происходит мгновенно. Как правильно нужно делать отправку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас есть бесконечный цикл, и форма отправляется только после того, что код приводит к такой ошибке:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

При нажатии на кнопке, валидация вырабатывается, потом вызывается `sendForm`, и `sendForm` вызывает `$('#form').submit`, которое заставляет валидацию вырабатываться, потом вызывается `sendForm`, и так далее.

Можно просто удалить функцию `sendForm`. Функция `submitHandler` тоже не нужна.

```js
$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    size: {
      required: true
    },
    form: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    size: {
      required: "Размер нужен"
    },
    form: {
      required: "Форма нужна"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="send.php" method="post" target="frame">
  <input type="text" name="size" placeholder="Размер *">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="form" placeholder="Форма *">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" class="rounded_button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```